# How to assign a specific IP to Apache Tomcat server

Tags: apache

I have installed Apache tomcat 6 on windows server 2008, i want to assign a specific IP to apache tomcat server, where i do that so that Apache should listen on that specific IP ?

Comment: Please accept answers to your previous questions...people spend time and energy looking for solutions to your queries, and if you don't accept the answer (and reward them) you're defeating the very purpose of the forum.

Comment: This is not a GISse question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit **server.xml** file.

Open up the Server.xml file and search for *Connector*.

The top Connector will have the port that you're trying to communicate through, in my case 8080. In between port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" type address="0.0.0.0" (Line will look like *port="8080" address="0.0.0.0" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"*).

Cheers!